# Adding new image on the top of recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to show the new updates on the top. I am using firebase and recyclerview.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Feed,FeedViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Feed, FeedViewHolder>(
                Feed.class,R.layout.news_feed_row,FeedViewHolder.class,mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FeedViewHolder viewHolder, Feed model, int position) {

               viewHolder.setdesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setimage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            }
        };
        mNews_Feed_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
    public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         View mView;
        public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setdesc(String desc){
            TextView post_desc_value = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc_card_view);
            post_desc_value.setText(desc);

        }
        public void setimage(final Context ctx, final String image){
            final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_card_view);
            Glide.with(ctx).load(image).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(post_image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the code properly

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your adapter and call it to add new item to the recycler view

```
public void addItem(Feed model){
    <your list name>.add(0, model);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
}
```

Comment: This is true in general, but in this case the question is about the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter where you can't access the <your list name>.